# How to get specified value from get-process

Tags: powershell

The below code produces a csv file, which itself contains a list of information about the current window such as window name, runtime, title and so on. How do i create variables from one or multiple of these items (without reading them from the output file)?

```
Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class Tricks {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
}
"@

destination=".\Documents"
csv_name="\activeProcess.csv"
$a = [tricks]::GetForegroundWindow()

get-process | ? { $_.mainwindowhandle -eq $a } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $destination$csv_name
```

Edit: `get-process | ? { $_.mainwindowhandle -eq $a }` produces the text:

```
"Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    733      43    65832      82612       5.64   7404   1 powershell"
```

Whereas I would like to specify "ProcessName" so can create a variable containing the string "powershell"

Solution:
enclosing the last ling in parenthesis and appending with ".ProcessName" solves this issue. For example:

```
(get-process | ? { $_.mainwindowhandle -eq $a }).ProcessName)
```

Comment: Is this what you mean? `$result = get-process | ? { $_.mainwindowhandle -eq $a }`

Comment: Not quite, as that would give me every entry of the output, when i only want to specify one. See edit in original post for details.

Comment: If you want to get the `processName` value then you could do `$result = (get-process | ? { $_.mainwindowhandle -eq $a }).ProcessName`

Comment: Thats it! much simpler solution than i expected, thank you